# Cloudwatch agent not using environment variable credentials on Windows

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I'm trying to configure an AMI using a script that installs the unified Cloudwatch agent on both AWS and on premise Windows machines by using static IAM credentials for both of them. As part of the script, I set the credentials statically (as a test) using

```
$Env:AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID="myaccesskey"
$Env:AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY="mysecretkey"
$Env:AWS_DEFAULT_REGION="us-east-1"
```

Once I have the AMI, I create a machine and connect to it, and then verify the credentials are there by running `aws configure list`

```
  Name                    Value             Type    Location
  ----                    -----             ----    --------
  profile                <not set>             None    None
  access_key     ****************C6IF          env
  secret_key     ****************SCnC          env
  region                us-east-1              env    ['AWS_REGION', 'AWS_DEFAULT_REGION']
```

But when I start the agent, I get the following error in the logs.

> 2022-12-26T17:51:49Z I! First time setting retention for log group test-cloudwatch-agent, update map to avoid setting twice
> 2022-12-26T17:51:49Z E! Failed to get credential from session: NoCredentialProviders: no valid providers in chain
> caused by: EnvAccessKeyNotFound: failed to find credentials in the environment.
> SharedCredsLoad: failed to load profile, .
> EC2RoleRequestError: no EC2 instance role found
> caused by: EC2MetadataError: failed to make EC2Metadata request

I'm using the Administrator user for both the installation of the agent and then when RDPing into the machine. Is there anything I'm missing?
I've already tried adding the credentials to the `.aws/credentials` file and modifying the `common-config.toml` file to use a profile. That way it works but in my case I just want to use the environment variables.

**EDIT**: I tested adding the credentials in the userdata script and modify a bit how they are created and now it seems to work.

```
$env:aws_access_key_id = "myaccesskeyid"  
$env:aws_secret_access_key = "mysecretaccesskey"    
[System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID',$env:aws_access_key_id,[System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine)      
[System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY',$env:aws_secret_access_key,[System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine)       
[System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION','us-east-1',[System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine)
```

Now the problem is that I'm trying to start the agent at the end of the userdata script with the command from the documentation but it does nothing (I see in the agent logs the command but there is no error). If I RDP into the machine and launch the same command in Powershell it works fine. The command is:

```
& "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AmazonCloudWatchAgent\amazon-cloudwatch-agent-ctl.ps1" -a fetch-config -m onPrem -s -c file:"C:\ProgramData\Amazon\AmazonCloudWatchAgent\amazon-cloudwatch-agent.json"
```

Comment: How are you starting the agent?

Comment: I use the command from the documentation. `& "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AmazonCloudWatchAgent\amazon-cloudwatch-agent-ctl.ps1" -a fetch-config -m onPrem -s -c file:"C:\ProgramData\Amazon\AmazonCloudWatchAgent\amazon-cloudwatch-agent.json"`

Comment: From the same powershell terminal where environment variables where exported?

Comment: I updated the question with some more data. I'm running everything as part of the EC2 userdata script

Answer (score 0):

I finally was able to make it work but I'm not sure of why it didn't before. I was using

```
$env:aws_access_key_id = "accesskeyid"  
$env:aws_secret_access_key = "secretkeyid"    
[System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID',$env:aws_access_key_id,[System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine)      
[System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY',$env:aws_secret_access_key,[System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine)       
[System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION','us-east-1',[System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine)
```

to set the variables but then the agent was failing to initialize. I had to add

```
$env:aws_default_region = "us-east-1"
```

so it was able to run. I couldn't find the issue before because on Windows server 2022 I don't get the logs from the execution. I had to try using Windows Server 2019 to actually see the error when launching the agent.

I still don't know why the environment variables I set in the machine scope worked once logged into the machine but not when using them as part of the userdata script.